# Disable autocomplete closing parenthesis around selected text

Tags: delphi

I'm currently using Delphi10, and when I have a block of code selected and type and opening parenthesis "(" then instead of Delphi replacing the selected text by the opening parenthesis, it rather keeps the text but adds the opening parenthesis at the start of the selected text and a closing parenthesis at the end of the selected text. But I want it to just delete the selected text and write the "(" I just typed, as if I had typed any other character.

I tried disabling all options in Tools --> Options --> Editor Options --> Code Insight, but the unwanted behavior continues. How do I change this?

Comment: Updated link: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Key_Mappings

Comment: And yes, that feature is rather annoying than useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a feature called [*smart surround keys*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Code_Editor#Smart_Surround_Keys). You can control it under [key mappings of your editor options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Key_Mappings).